# Why estimator_weight in SAMME.R AdaBoost algorithm is set to 1

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, adaboost, ensemble-learning

I am new to AdaBoost algorithm. In [sklearn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py) **SAMME** algorithm's _boost_discrete() [returns](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py#L583) classifiers weight as "**estimator_weight**"

```
def _boost_discrete(self, iboost, X, y, sample_weight):
    .......

    return sample_weight, estimator_weight, estimator_error
```

But, for **SAMME.R** algorithm, "_boost_real()" is [returning](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py#L530) '1' instead of returning the estimator weight.

```
def _boost_real(self, iboost, X, y, sample_weight):
    .......

    return sample_weight, 1., estimator_error
```

My question is why SAMME.R algorithm returning the estimator_weight as '1'.
I am following ref [1]. Please help me understanding the algorithm. Thanks in advance.

Ref:
[1]J. Zhu, H. Zou, S. Rosset, T. Hastie, "Multi-class AdaBoost", 2009.

Comment: Please consider adding the relevant parts of the code and provide links to the codebase.

Comment: I have added the links. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's my understanding of why the weight may be set to '1' in the SAMME.R algorithm following this [Multi-class Adaboost](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/samme.pdf) paper from 2006. The 2009 paper you mentioned does not include the SAMME.R algorithm.

In the paper (2006) `sample_weight` is represented by **w** and `estimator_weight` is represented by **alpha**.

If you take a look at **Algorithm 2** SAMME

[image: SAMME Algorithm]

once the **w**'s and **alpha**'s are learned new samples are classified according to **C(x)**. Note that the `estimator_weight` (**alpha^(m)**) appears in **C(x)** and can be interpreted as the strength of the update for weak learner **m**.

Now let's look at **Algorithm 4** SAMME.R.

[image]

Note that `estimator_weight` (**alpha**) does not appear anywhere in this algorithm. Instead, the weak learners are characterized by the weighted class probabilities estimates and new samples are classified according to this new **C(x)**. Even though `estimator_weight` (**alpha**) does not directly appear in **C(x)**, one could place it in front of **h_k^(m)(x)** (as a multiplier) and define it to be 1 for all **alpha**:

[image]

This results in all the `estimator_weight` to take on a value of 1 at the end of training.